# не удается обработать и вернуть json из post запроса от яндекс.диалог yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2, яндекс-диалог

Написал контроллер для обработки POST-запроса

```
namespace frontend\modules\yandexDialog\controllers {

use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use Yii;

final class IndexController extends \frontend\controllers\FrontendController {

    public $content;

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['get', 'post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex() {

        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        
        ///$delim
        $apiRequestArray = json_decode(trim($request->post()), true);
        
        $this->content = ' {
            "response" : {
                    "text":"' . $apiRequestArray['text'] . '",
                    "buttons":[
                    {
                    "title":"Надпись на кнопке",
                            "payload":{

                            },
                            "url":"https://example.com/",
                            "hide":true
                    }
                    ],
                    "end_session":false
                    },
            "session": {
                "session_id":"' . $apiRequestArray['session']['session_id'] . '",
                    "message_id":"' . $apiRequestArray['session']['message_id'] . '",
                    "user_id":"' . $apiRequestArray['session']['user_id'] . '"
                    },
            "version":"' . $apiRequestArray['version'] . '"
            }';
        
        //$delim = ',';
        //$this->content .= ']}';
        $response = \Yii::$app->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->getHeaders()->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        $response->data = $this->content;
        $response->send(); 
     }

   }

}
```

В POST, по идее, приходит JSON следующего вида:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "locale": "ru-RU",
    "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
    "client_id": "ru.yandex.searchplugin/5.80 (Samsung Galaxy; Android 4.4)"
  },
  "request": {
     "command": "где ближайшее отделение",
     "original_utterance": "Алиса спроси у Сбербанка где ближайшее отделение",
     "type": "SimpleUtterance",
     "markup": {
        "dangerous_context": true
     },
     "payload": {}
  },
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "message_id": 4,
    "session_id": "2eac4854-fce721f3-b845abba-20d60",
    "skill_id": "3ad36498-f5rd-4079-a14b-788652932056",
    "user_id": "AC9WC3DF6FCE052E45A4566A48E6B7193774B84814CE49A922E163B8B29881DC"
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Но при попытке отправить данный JSON например, через Postman получаю ошибку HTTP `400 Bad Request`.

Что я делаю не так с приемом/обработкой JSON'a? Или в чем вообще проблема?

P.S вот [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/dialogs/alice/doc/protocol-docpage/) написано как должен выглядеть ответ, поэтому возвращаемый мною JSON имеет такой вид

P.S.S Вот что записывается в итоге в `$this->content`:

```
{"response":{"text":"","buttons":[{"title":"Надпись на кнопке","payload":{},"url":"https://example.com/","hide":true}],"end_session":false},"session":{"session_id":"","message_id":"","user_id":""},"version":""}
```

Comment: Что записывается в `$this->content` в итоге?

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko дополнил вопрос ответом на ваш вопрос) (простите за тавтологию)

Comment: Не работал с API яндекса, но, подозреваю, что `"session":{"session_id":"","message_id":"","user_id":""},"version":""` эти поля могут быть обязательными, а они у вас заполняются пустыми строками. Хотя, яндексу тогда стоило бы возвращать 403 ошибку

Comment: В описании API ведь отмечены обязательные поля: `text`, `end_session`, `session`, `session_id`, `message_id`, `user_id`, `version`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что содержит `$request->post()`

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko он пустой потому что до меня POST не доходит и поэтому не заполняется ничем) в этом и проблема, я думаю, но правда, не знаю как это решить. В $request->post() соответственно пустота потому что там должен находится JSON, но не работает почему то, не принимает JSON

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET);` в `index.php` и посмотрите, что в каком формате вам приходит. Проследите, где теряется

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko хорошо) а с ограничением сервера это никак не может быть связанно? может сис админа о чем то надо попросить?

Comment: Может быть и с ограничениями сервера связано, но лучше попробуйте сами отправить post-запрос на этот контроллер с каким-нибудь тестовым полем, и выведите результат через `var_dump`

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko так я и делаю, а мне возвращается 400-ая ошибка HTTP 
"Bad request"